# Assigning function to a dictionary key - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem, where I'm assigning function to an "entry" in dictionary.
This is from the code:

```
assignment[message[0]] = self.request.sendall
if members == 0:
    for request in assignment:
        request("PING")
        print(request)
        print("Sent PING")
```

And this is the traceback. From what I understand, it thinks I'm trying to call a string.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 295, in_handle_request_noblock
 self.process_request(request, client_address)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
 self.finish_request(request, client_address)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
 self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 655, in __init__
 self.handle()
 File "C:\Users\Radek Golan\Desktop\Sequencer\Sequencer_Server.py", line 58, in handle
 request("PING")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

And this is the dictionary being listed out:

```
{'nick1': <bound method _socketobject.sendall of <socket._socketobject object at 0x02883EA0>>, 'nick2': <bound method _socketobject.sendall of <socket._socketobject object at 0x02883FB8>>}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your iteration here:

```
for request in assignment:
```

Is giving you the *keys*  of your dictionary. Not the values. To get the values when iterating the way you are, you want:

```
for request in assignment:
    print(assignment[request])
```

or

```
for key, value in assignment.items():
    print("key {}".format(key))
    print("value {}".format(value))
```

Even more simple just use `values` instead:

```
for value in assignment.values():
    print(value)
```

Take a look at the dictionary documentation to get more acquainted with it:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Or `for value in assignent.values()`.

Comment: Or `for value in assignment.itervalues()` in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

for loops over dictionaries iterate over the keys.  your `request` variable will have `"nick1"` in it.  You need `assignment[request]("Ping")`.